# Como selecionar um arquivo em Python usando o Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Tenho o seguinte código em Python usando a biblioteca `tkinter`:

```
from tkinter import *


class Application:
 def __init__(self, master=None):
  self.widget1 = Frame(master)
  self.widget1.pack()
  self.msg = Label(self.widget1, text="Busque o arquivo")
  self.msg["font"] = ("Calibri", "9", "italic")
  self.msg.pack()
  self.sair = Button(self.widget1)
  self.sair["text"] = "Buscar"
  self.sair["font"] = ("Calibri", "9")
  self.sair["width"] = 10
  self.sair["command"] = self.mudarTexto
  self.sair.pack()
  self.msg2 = Label(self.widget1, text="")
  self.msg2["font"] = ("Calibri", "9", "italic")
  self.msg2.pack()

 def mudarTexto(self):
  if self.msg["text"] == "Busque o arquivo":
     #Teria que abrir a pasta do windows aqui
     self.msg2["text"] = "NOME DO ARQUIVO AQUI"



root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

No momento esse código apenas imprime uma mensagem quando o botão é pressionado, porém, gostaria que ao clicar no botão, abrisse uma pasta no windows para selecionar **apenas um arquivo**, e que após selecionado e dado o Ok, o nome do arquivo fosse impresso no programa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # Isto torna oculto a janela principal
filename = askopenfilename() # Isto te permite selecionar um arquivo
print(filename) # printa o arquivo selecionado
```

[Seguem outras funções que podem ser do seu interesse](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/CS152f17/GUIandEventDrivenProgramming/02_standard_dialog_boxes.html)

Answer (score 3):

Para exibir caixas de diálogo de manipulação de arquivos, use as funções do submódulo `tkinter.filedialog`:

```
from tkinter import filedialog as dlg
path = dlg.askopenfilename()
```

Segue abaixo uma lista das funções desse módulo, para referência:

> ```
> askdirectory(**options)
> ```

Pede ao usuário por uma pasta e retorna o caminho para ela

> ```
> askopenfile(mode='r', **options)
> ```

Pede ao usuário por um arquivo, e já retorna o arquivo aberto

> ```
> askopenfilename(**options)
> ```

Pede ao usuário por um arquivo e retorna o caminho para ele

> ```
> askopenfilenames(**options)
> ```

Pede ao usuário para selecionar vários arquivos. Retorna uma lista dos nomes dos arquivos ou uma lista vazia se o usuário cancelar a janela.

> ```
> askopenfiles(mode='r', **options)
> ```

Pede ao usuário para selecionar vários arquivos. Retorna uma lista com os arquivos já abertos ou uma lista vazia se o usuário cancelar a janela.

> ```
> asksaveasfile(mode='w', **options)
> ```

Pede ao usuário um nome de arquivo para ser salvo, e retorna o arquivo já criado e aberto para escrita

> ```
> asksaveasfilename(**options)
> ```

Pede ao usuário um nome de arquivo para ser salvo, e retorna o caminho para ele. Se o arquivo já existir, o usuário terá que confirmar sobrescrever.